# Which is faster, 2 SSD drives , each plugged into a sata 6 port on RAID 0, or 1 SSD drive plugged into a sata express port (10gb)

Tags: ssd, raid

I have a new motherboard and it has 1 sata express port that's up to 10gb transfer. So I'm wondering which would have better performance? 2 SSD on raid 0 in a sata 6 port or 1 SSD on a sata express port?

Answer (score 2):

Here is some good benchmark data with a single or RAID 0 of SSDs on SATA, just for some background to start.

http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/ssd-raid-benchmark,3485-4.html

"In fact, the two striped 256 GB drives provide about twice the performance of the single drives [in sequential read and write]."

"At the low queue depths you normally encounter in a desktop environment, all of these configurations perform fairly similarly. In fact, the striped setups are even a bit slower than single drives. This is because we're taxing the NAND flash's throughput."

"Once we jump up into very high queue depths, both RAID-based arrangements distinguish themselves. It's only a shame that this is very atypical of any desktop workload, so you won't see it unless you take the 840 Pros into a more enterprise application."

So I personally wouldn't complicate the setup by using RAID 0 - since it has less clear of a benefit with SSDs particularly with everyday consumer usage, and it doubles your chance of failure. And if using a PCI Express SSD is an option, then that would definitely beat out the RAID 0 option for speed and other considerations. The PCI Express SSDs have been quite a bit faster every time I've come across them in articles.

Answer (score 1):

One new, high performance SSD will saturate the 550Mb/s transfer rate of SATA3 6Gb. Two in RAID0 would see a max throughput of about 1Gb/s.

On the other hand, a SATAe PCIe 3.0 port, using two lanes (x2) can reach nearly 2Gb/s which will allow for around 3.5x more bandwidth for data throughput. This is the standard most consumer PCI SSD drives will operate with.

Some PCI SSD's will even reach this bandwidth limit and saturate the connection, meaning they have to be connected to a x4 (PCI 3.0) or x8 (PCI 2.0) connection to utilise the greater number of lanes to provide the maximum throughput.

SATAe drives are, however more costly £/Gb than conventional SATA drives and you need to make sure you purchase a boot-able drive.

Therefore logic dictates (to me at least) that you should go for the PCI SATAe SSD if you want the fastest solution to your storage needs.